# Dataset for experimenting with road networks with graph algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on a kind of geographic problem, specifically finding the fastest path for an Electric Vehicle.

So to facilitate the experimentations of the algorithms I've created I need some kind of road network dataset. I have been looking at some real world data sets such as *OpenStreetMap*, but this seems like an awfully complicated thing to integrate.

All I really need is a road network dataset that contains distances and speed limits, being able to work with it in python is preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Researchers frequently use graphs from the [9th DIMACS Implementation Challenge](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/challenge9/download.shtml) for experiments with their shortest-path algorithms. Coordinates, distances, and estimated travel times all are provided. The format is simple and textual; I estimate that a dozen lines of Python would suffice to read them.